# Dependency Injection Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, optional-parameters

Is it considered a bad practice to use optional parameters when using dependency injection frameworks with Constructor injection?

Example:

```
public class ProductsController
{
    public ProductsController(IProductService productService = null, IBackOrderService = null)
    {
    }
}
```

I have specified both parameters as optional, but my DI framework will always inject both dependencies. If I add a new action to my controller which requires a new dependency, would it be bad to make the new dependency optional? I could potentially be breaking dozens of unit tests even though the existing tests wouldn't require the new dependency.

**Edit**
People seem to be confused by my question. I am never construcing a ProductsController manually in my web application. This is handled by a controller factory (which automatically injects dependencies).

What I don't like is having a unit test like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var controller = new ProductsController(new MockProductService(), new MockBackOrderService());
}
```

Now I decide to add a new action method to my controller. This new action needs a new dependency but none of the existing actions do. Now I have to go back and modify 100 different unit tests because I added a new parameter. I can avoid that by making the parameters optional, but I wanted to know if it was a bad idea. My gut feeling says no because the only thing it affects are the unit tests.

Comment: How does `ProductsController` operate without its dependancies?

Comment: @Matthew Certain pieces of ProductsController would operate without EVERY dependency. Obviously the DI container will always inject all the dependencies, though.

Comment: I'm never instantiating my controller manually except in my unit tests. That is why I was wondering if it even matters if I make the parameters optional. The parameters will always be injected (outside of my unit tests) by default.

Comment: if they are always injected in your production code what are you testing then if you don't pass those dependencies? It doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'm using mocks for my unit tests? I don't use dependency injection to inject mocks into the controllers. That seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea. Constructor injection means that the **dependencies are required**. You should even add the guard lines that throws if one of the parameters is null.

I think the problem is with your unit tests. For instance I have only one place where the controller is created and supporting objects are mocked (controllerContext, HttpContext, Request, Response, etc.). Then if I add a new parameter in the constructor I have to change it only in one place in the unit tests.

Maybe you should consider to code a generic base class in your unit tests, or make a usage of "setup" routine for the tests.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I probably do need to refactor my unit tests to only be doing setup in a single place. Right now I have been struggling with it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm interested to know why this isn't a good idea. What's wrong with an optional parameter, say `IMyDependency myDependency = null`, then having the constructor use a default implementation if it's not present - `if (myDependency == null) myDependency = new NullMyDependency`.  It seems to me that there are some cases where it's useful, and it seems to work with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: @Joe Generally constructor injection means parameters are required and I applied this principle before optional parameters were a thing. Your object is initialized with passed in parameters and you're done. For optional things a property injection was generally used. It's a matter of expressing your API. Of course, if you provide meaningful defaults  for optional constructor parameters it would work as well. Just a matter of taste

Comment: An example of where this may be necessary is when creating a library that could be used in different situations. Sometimes those components may not have been registered and they may not be vital to the operation of the service. What you end up having to do is inject in either the service provider of a scoped service provider and resolving it manually. No we are having to inject in the service locator. But I agree using this approach to solve injecting dependencies for unit testing is wrong.

Answer (score 19):

**I completely agree with the accepted answer** for all the cases on that defining a Dependency means that implementation will not work with out it.

**But what if** you have something that does not necessarily need a dependency but you want to be able to configure something if that dependency has been loaded. OK...? that sounds a bit weird but its a valid Meta Programming use case - and you think maybe factory pattern could help.. but even the factory **may need some, none or all dependencies** so Factory does not solve this problem.

> Real world problem of feature flags. If a feature is turned off you
>   don't need that dependency.. or maybe cant even create it because
>   there is no concrete implementation. So its turned off. It compiles,
>   everything works OK. But then somebody switches the feature on and all
>   of a sudden we need that dependency.

I found a way to do this -- and the best part is I only realised how to do this by learning about another not so well known technique with Dependency Injection (I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection)

**Injecting several concrete implementations for a single Interface**

```
services.AddTransient<IWarehouseRepo, ActionRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IWarehouseRepo, EventRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IWarehouseRepo, AuditRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IWarehouseRepo, ProRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IWarehouseRepo, SuperWarehouseRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IWarehouseRepo, InferiorWarehouseRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IWarehouseRepo, MonthlyStatisticsRepository>();
```

I only learnt recently that this is completely valid but for this to work your constructor needs to look like this..

```
public WarehouseHandler(IEnumerable<IWarehouseRepo> repos)
```

So that is super cool! I can select a repository I need based on whatever criteria. But **how does this help with Optional Dependencies?**

Because this type of constructor **will give you 0** or more dependencies.  So **if you do not add any dependencies** you can branch out in the constructor using a conditional statement

```
  if (repos.Count() == 0)
    return;
```

This is null reference safe, does not require default values, easy to debug, easy to read and easy to implement.

You can now also use this technique as the feature switch mechanism too!

Comment: Upvoted - it may not be what the OP was asking for exactly but certainly helps in situations not necessarily unit test related.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [The Test Data Builder pattern](http://defragdev.com/blog/?p=147).

In the simplest form it could be done as static test helper method

```
public ProductsController BuildControllerWIthMockDependencies ()
{
    var controller = new ProductsController(new MockProductService(), new MockBackOrderService());
return controller;
}
```

You can  use [AutoFixture as a generic Test Data Builder](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/07/01/AutoFixtureAsTestDataBuilder/).

Further techniques for using Test Data Builders can be found in [Test Data Builders: an alternative to the Object Mother pattern](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer as a good and commonly used way to make setting up the test easier for you. But I would like to answer your question about why it's not ok to leave them as optional.

It's a good idea to test every possible scenario for negative cases. You would want to ensure that all other things equal in your test setup, that supplying or not supplying the dependency does or doesn't change the outcome. Following this approach of strictly testing all scenarios, you are creating yet another scenario to be tested when your original intention was to reduce the amount of code going into your unit tests.

Making the constructor arguments required leaves no other option and reduces the amount of unnecessary scenarios to check. In the case you don't expect the dependency to be needed, the mock can be set to strict with no setups, which will actively validate that it wasn't used.

I am currently looking at a scenario where I want an optional dependency, but it's for a use case outside of unit testing. In my case, I'm adding ILogger as a dependency to some of a library's classes. I don't want it to be required because the calling application should provide the DI registration for this, or they may not have one, and I don't want this to cause a breaking change.

So it's not always a bad practice, but in your case I would say it is.